# Exports in SAS - to a common share drive

Tags: sas, export, share, drive

I would like to export a SAS dataset to an excel file on a Share Drive.

I use the Proc Export procedure, and exporting using the export on the Node it still doesn't place the file on the Share drive.

I am connected to the work network when doing this and I still cant seem to drop the document there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is advised to provide as much helpful information as possible, to make it easier for the community to provide good and precise answers. At minimum you should provide some code samples and a more detailed description of the error that you are getting (if any).

Comment: Please paste the relevant part of your log here (indented by 4 blanks). Also specify if you run your SAS application locally or remote and if you use SAS Enterprice Guide or not.

Comment: Is your SAS local installation or a server? What OS is running on the server?

Comment: Are you using SAS EG? If so, is it on a server and can that server see your shared drive?